# Application Updater

Tags: deployment, installation, windows

does anybody know a good, flexible and free component for automatic application updating beside ClickOnce (not necessarily .NET only)?
In the past there was the Updater Application Block from Microsoft. But as far as i know its not maintained anymore.

What Technology are you using to keep you applications up to date?

Answer (score 0):

We have designed our own updater logic based on WiX & .NET for our .NET apps. Logic is fairly simple and couple with continuous integration (so that we can fire a new release in a single click). Everything is released as open source. You can have a look at the code at http://code.google.com/p/lokad-sdk/ and more precisely at http://tinyurl.com/kwrhvo (direct app source code).

Answer (score 0):

Try [PADUpdater](http://software-algorithms.com/PADUpdater) it's freeware and doesn't need any configuration as it uses your [PAD.XML](http://pad.asp-software.org) file to get the settings.